# Make Problem in Qt for Embedded Linux Installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qtembedded

I'm following [this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qt-embedded-install.html) article to install qt for embedded linux on my host machine (which runs Ubuntu). So far, I successfully ./configure'd it but when I type "make" or "make install" it gives this error:

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

I'm a Linux newbie so I don't know if I'm missing obvious here, so I'd appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: Changing command line to this solved my problem.

./configure -embedded arm -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ -prefix \
/usr/local/qt -little-endian -webkit -no-qt3support -no-cups -no-largefile \
-optimized-qmake -no-openssl -nomake tools -qt-mouse-tslib -qt-kbd-linuxinput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing command line to this solved my problem. ./configure -embedded arm -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ -prefix \ /usr/local/qt -little-endian -webkit -no-qt3support -no-cups -no-largefile \ -optimized-qmake -no-openssl -nomake tools -qt-mouse-tslib -qt-kbd-linuxinput